# Do vendor entries go through tree shaking on Webpack?

Tags: webpack, tree-shaking

I am tuning a project's `webpack.config.js` to optimize cache and and it's entry is something among those lines:

```
entry: {
    main: "./index",
    vendor: [
        "react",
        "react-dom",
        "material-ui",
    ],
}
```

As `material-ui` uses ES6 modules, I wonder if it is still tree shaken when included in a different entry or if it is included as is.

Bonus question: how could I detected that based on the stats json?